# windows popup onload event not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, onload, popupwindow

```
let newWindow = open('https://javascript.info', 'example', 'width=300,height=300');
newWindow.onload=()=>{
 alert("Popup Loaded");
}
```

Onload event was not triggering after the popup window is loaded.

Comment: CORS will prevent you from accessing the new window in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not the same domain , you will not be able to access the window set properties.

Try this here in console

```
(function(ow) {
    ow.addEventListener("load", function() { alert("loaded"); }, false);
   
})(window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'example', 'width=300,height=300'));
```

This will work

But if you put a different domain , it will not work. You'd have to use `PostMessage` or something else.